# Create SEO Friendly URLS doesn't work (.htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I created an htaccess i want to rename all extension .php files to .html
i put

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.php  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php $1.html [R=301,L]  
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.html  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1.php [L]
```

and it work fine.
Now i want to rename nettoyage-detail-bureaux.php?id=21 to nettoyage-detail-bureaux-21.html
so i add

```
RewriteRule ^nettoyage-detail-bureaux-([0-9]+)\.html$ nettoyage-detail-bureaux.html?id=$1 [L]
```

it doesn't work.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have a typo at the end where you have `.html?id=$1` it should be `.php?id=$1`

So try this.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^nettoyage-detail-bureaux-([0-9]+)\.html$ nettoyage-detail-bureaux.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.php  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php $1.html [R=301,L]  
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.html  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1.php [L]
```